# How do count consecutive wins/losses and make it reset once the winning/losing streak is broken?

Tags: c

I have the idea in my head but I just cant write it into a program. I'm having a hard time but its so simple.
What I want to do is if eg.: LA Lakers wins 5 games in a row, I want to assign that to a counter, and when they lose I want the counter to reset but I don't know how.

So far what I've got is:

What I want to do is the following but I just don't know how to do it: (obviously not how I would write it)

```
if game is lost, count is 1
    streak = streak + 1
(streak is 1)

if game is lost again count is 2
    streak = streak + 1
(streak is 2)

if game is won count is reset and streak is 1
    streak = streak + 1
(streak became 0)
(streak is 1)

if game is won, count is 2
    streak = streak + 1
(streak is 2)

if game is won count is 3
    streak = streak + 1
(streak is 3)

if game is lost count is 1
    streak = streak + 1
(streak became 0)
(streak is 1)
       *
       *
       *
       *
```

Comment: The answer to all "no idea how to start" questions is: "read, find working examples, try, fix, redo". I.e. read some text book or tutorial, find a HelloWorld or sample code, try to change it in small steps towards your goal, test, debug; then try the next iteration. Once you got something and it does not work for the very small change you made away from something working, then it is time to ask a focused question here, according to [ask] and maybe using the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Your first milestone is to be able to read input which has the information whether the team won or lost. You need to define how to do that. Maybe you read "win win win win loss win loss win loss loss". Or you read more boolean like, as "1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0", because that makes everything else much easier. You need to decide that. Then find out how to read the first of the infos. Then you need to learn outputting it. Then to store it. Then to store multiple instances of that info in a compound variable. Then learn counting. First only count ALL wins, just to start. Then ask on the streaks here.

Comment: And just in case it is related to the background of what you are trying, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: And, just to be a bit more helpful in this case (though only if you have some minimum practise already): Read up on "if else".

Comment: You want to do all the streaks in a few seconds... or over several hours/days/months (in real-time, updating as games finish)?

Answer (score 3):

If they win during a losing streak, you need to reset the counter.

If they lose during a winning streak, you need to reset the counter.

You obviously know whether it's a win or a loss. The other piece of information needed is whether they're currently in a winning streak or losing streak. This is simply a need to remember the previous input.

1. Set streak type to win.
2. Set streak length to zero.
3. For each event input,

   1. If the event type doesn't match the streak type,

      1. Set streak type to the event type.
      2. Set streak length to zero.
   2. Increment the streak length.
   3. Output current state.

Comment: Nice answer... I was preparing the same but with code. Just giving the algo and leave the coding to OP is much better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually figured it out on my own but I didn't want to believe its easy. :)